# Where is the enclosing lexical scope in this code?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I do not understand why calling the logout method logs the window object, when the parent of the method is the object user. The the parent of the logout method is the user.

```
      let user = {
      name:'Jess',
      age:17,
      logout:()=>{
      console.log(this);
      }
      };

      user.logout()
```

Comment: Objects don't have an [execution context](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-executable-code-and-execution-contexts), there is only  global, function and eval contexts (and no one uses eval). Since it's global code, the arrow function's enclosing context is the global context, so its *this* is the global object.

Comment: You are confusing scope with execution context. There are originally only two scopes global son function. Objects don’t create execution contexts, well kind of as the children don’t create parents. Each execution contexts creates its own object. https://codeburst.io/js-demystified-04-execution-context-97dea52c8ac6

Answer (score 0):

You are capturing the `this` with an arrow function. Compare with this:

```js
let user = {
  name: 'Jess',
  age: 17,
  logout: function() {
    console.log(this);
  }
};

user.logout()
```

Answer (score 0):

"the value of `this` is determined by how a function is called (runtime binding). It can't be set by assignment during execution, and it may be different each time the function is called. ES5 introduced the `bind()` method to set the value of a function's this regardless of how it's called, and ES2015 introduced arrow functions which don't provide their own `this` binding (it retains the this value of the enclosing lexical context)." [this mdn web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

"arrow functions don’t bind this to the object that called them. They just use the value of this in the scope in which they were defined. In this case, that’s the global object. So arrow functions are unusable for object methods." [Advantages and Pitfalls of Arrow Functions](https://medium.com/tfogo/advantages-and-pitfalls-of-arrow-functions-a16f0835799e)